# How to add a rasterised line feature to raster via raster calculator in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster-calculator, rasterization, summarizing

I want to sum different layers (Population Density, Land Use, Rivers, Roads) to derive an Exposure map for landslides using the raster calculator in ArcGIS.

First I converted the two line shapes (Rivers & Roads) into raster. Then I aggregated both to be able to reclassify.
Afterwards I reclassified(standardised) the raster files in order to be able to weight them.

Summing raster LU and PopDens works flawless, but as soon as I add one of the rastered line features, the result looks like it uses them as mask --> only cells, where river or road occurs are considered, instead of the whole study area.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the raster calculator to use the extents of the smallest dataset. There are a few ways to work around this, but I think your quickest solution might be to first use the [Copy Raster tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-raster.htm) with your rasterized lines as the input raster and the larger layer as the [Snap Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/snap-raster.htm) in the "Environments" to create a raster with the same extents as the larger raster.

From here, use the [Con](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm) and [IsNull](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/gp_toolref/spatial_analyst_tools/is_null.htm) functions of the raster calculator. You can conditionally check areas where your larger extent rasterized lines are null/NoData (i.e. places that they don't exist) and then set these areas to the value of the already summed output(s). In areas where the rasterized lines *do* exist, set the value to the sum of their cells plus the already summed output(s).

```
Con(IsNull("YourModifiedExtentLinesLayerName"),"YourAlreadySummedLayers",("YourAlreadySummedLayers"+"YourModifiedExtentLinesLayerName")
```

This will result in an output with the same extents as "YourAlreadySummedLayers" with the values already summed for the rasterized line areas.

Putting it all together as a model might be helpful if you haven't already:
[image]

The expression in the model noted above is basically the same as my example, but with inline variable substitution:

```
Con(IsNull("%LargerExtentRasterLines%"),"%Lulc%",("%Lulc%"+"%LargerExtentRasterLines%"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I tried your solution and I get the same output like when I first sum Lulc + PopDens and then Rivers + Roads and then sum the results (instead of summing all simultaneously).
The output is a whole study area raster with values exceeding the original values (0-20) by multiples (0-39.350). Could it have something to do with different pixel types (input rasters are signed or unsigned integer)

Comment: The differences in the outputs occur depending on the aggregation. If aggregated it works (with the suggested calculation by @AHigh). I assumed the multiple "overlaps" of smaller line rasters with (i.e.) lulc raster are calculated accordingly. But it turns out, they have to be resampled/aggregated before (which did not work with my calculation).

Answer (score 0):

If the area surrounding the rivers or roads (i.e. areas of non-roads) are classed as NoData this will act as a mask. You need to reclassify your rivers and roads so that NoData has a value (maybe 0 or 1 depending on how you are combining them)

You will need to set your processing extent (under the Environment button in the tool) to match your study area limits

Comment: yes, I thought of this solution as well....would have been my choice, if the above mentioned had failed